# Why is my Curve rectangle not visible as an object in Curve settings?

Tags: bezier-curves

After creating a Bezier Curve I also created a Curve Rectangle that I want to use as the object in the Curve options on the BezierCurve.

However, when I want to choose my rectangle within these options I cannot see the rectangle, I can only choose the BezierCurve.

How can I choose the rectangle as an object in Curve settings for my BezierCurve?

[image]

Comment: You can't use a bevel object on itself

Comment: That is what I am saying. I want to use the Rectangle on the BezierCurve, but I cannot choose the rectangle

Comment: What @DuarteFarrajotaRamos wants to tell you is, you are currently in the settings for the rectangle as you can see by the name above the settings. Also in the _Outliner_ above the Bézier curve is dark orange, which means it's not the active selected object (on which you could change the settings), but the highlighted curve symbol on Rectangle.002 shows it is the active object. The reason it is not shown in bright orange is, you selected the Bézier curve while you were in _Edit Mode_ on the rectangle, which shows as if it is deselected, but you are still actively in _Edit Mode_ there.

Comment: Ah, that's clear! I understand it now

Comment: Yeah the outliner highlighting can be a bit finicky like that, there's the *active & selected row* color (bright blue background, yellow font), the *selected row* color (deep blue background, orange font) and the *active object* highlight (light gray rounded square around the mesh icon). An object can be active without being selected. :)